# Достать логин по id

Tags: mysql, sql

Имею следующий запрос для вывода данных в таблицу:

```
   SELECT j.id AS jid,
j.product_id AS pid,
j.user_id AS wid,
j.datex AS jdate, 
j.count AS count, 
j.storage_id AS storage_id, 
u.id AS uid, 
u.name AS login, 
u.group_id AS groupn, 
p.name AS product_name,
p.id AS proid
   FROM s_reports AS j, 
s_users AS u, 
s_products AS p
   WHERE j.user_id = u.id
AND j.product_id = p.id
```

Необходимо вывести `u.name` из таблицы `s_users`, где `s_reports.storage_id == s_users.id`.
Бьюсь, но желаемого результата не получаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял требуемое, то

```
SELECT j.id AS jid,
    j.product_id AS pid,
    j.user_id AS wid,
    j.datex AS jdate, 
    j.count AS count, 
    j.storage_id AS storage_id, 
    u.id AS uid, 
    u.name AS login, 
    u.group_id AS groupn, 
    p.name AS product_name,
    p.id AS proid,
    u2.name
FROM s_reports AS j, 
    s_users AS u, 
    s_products AS p,
    s_users AS u2
WHERE j.user_id = u.id
    AND j.product_id = p.id
    AND j.storage_id = u2.id
```